# How to define "apply" in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, apply

I am trying to define a function that is similar to Lisp's `apply`. Here is my attempt:

```ml
type t =
  | Str of string
  | Int of int

let rec apply f args =
  match args with
  | (Str s)::xs -> apply (f s) xs
  | (Int i)::xs -> apply (f i) xs
  | [] -> f

(* Example 1 *)
let total = apply (fun x y z -> x + y + z)
                  [Int 1; Int 2; Int 3]

(* Example 2 *)
let () = apply (fun name age ->
                  Printf.printf "Name: %s\n" name;
                  Printf.printf "Age: %i\n" age)
               [Str "Bob"; Int 99]
```

However, this fails to compile. The compiler gives this error message:

```
File "./myprog.ml", line 7, characters 25-30:
7 |   | (Str s)::xs -> apply (f s) xs
                             ^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         string -> 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside string -> 'a
```

What is the meaning of this error message? How can I fix the problem and implement `apply`?

Comment: What's the type of `f` in your apply function?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix an untyped DSL for data:

```ml
type t =
| Int of int
| Float of float
```

and a shallow embedding (using OCaml functions as functions inside the DSL) for functions in apply

```
let rec apply f args =
  match args with
  | (Str s)::xs -> apply (f s) xs (* f is int -> 'a *)
  | (Int i)::xs -> apply (f i) xs  (* f is string -> 'a *) 
  | [] -> f (* f is 'a *)
```

The typechecker is complaining that if `f` has type `'a`, `f s` cannot  also have for type `'a` since it would mean that `f` has simultaneously type `string -> 'a` and `'a` (without using the recursive types flag).
And more generally, your function `apply` doesn't use `f` with a coherent type: sometimes it has type `'a`, sometimes it has type `int -> 'a`, other times it would rather have type `string -> 'a`. In other words, it is not possible to write a type for `apply`

```ml
val apply: ??? (* (int|string) -> ... *) -> t list -> ???
```

You have to choose your poison.

Either go with a fully untyped DSL which contains functions, that can be applied:

```ml
type t =
| Int of int
| Float of float
| Fun of (t -> t)

exception Type_error
let rec apply f l = match f, l with
| x, [] -> f
| Fun f, a :: q -> apply (f a) q
| (Int _|Float _), _ :: _ -> raise Type_error
```

or use OCaml type system and define a well-typed list of arguments with a GADT:

```ml
type ('a,'b) t =
| Nil: ('a,'a) t
| Cons: 'a * ('b,'r) t -> ('a -> 'b,'r) t
 
let rec apply: type f r. f -> (f,r) t -> r = fun f l ->
match l with
| Nil -> f
| Cons (x,l) -> apply (f x) l
```

EDIT:
Using the GADT solution is quite direct since we are using usual OCaml type without much wrapping:

```ml
let three = apply (+) (Cons(1, Cons(2,Nil)))
```

(and we could use a heterogeneous list syntactic sugar to make this form even lighter syntactically)

The untyped DSL requires to build first a function in the DSL:

```ml
let plus = Fun(function
  | Float _ | Fun _ -> raise Type_error
  | Int x -> Fun(function
    | Float _ | Fun _ -> raise Type_error
    | Int y -> Int (x+y)
    )
  )
```

but once we have built the function, it is relatively straightforward:

```
let three = apply_dsl plus [Int 2; Int 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you provide usage examples for the untyped DSL solution and the GADT solution?

Comment: What is a "heterogeneous list syntactic sugar"?

Comment: You could define the type t as `type ('a,'b) t = []: ('a,'a) t | (::) : 'a * ('b,'r) t -> ('a -> 'b,'r) t` which redefine the usual list constructors. With this definition, the GADT apply example can be rewriten as `let three = apply (+) [1;2]`.

Answer (score 1):

```ml
type t =
  | Str of string
  | Int of int
  | Unit

let rec apply f args =
  match args with
  | x::xs -> apply (f x) xs
  | [] -> f Unit
```

Let's go step by step:

- line 1: `apply : 'a -> 'b -> 'c` (we don't know the types of `f`, `args` and `apply`'s return type
- line 2 and beginning of line 3: `args : t list` so `apply : 'a -> t list -> 'c`
- rest of line 3: Since `f s` (`s : string`), `f : string -> 'a` but `f t : f` because `apply (f s)`. This means that `f` contains `f` in its type, this is a buggy behaviour

It's actually buggy to call `f` on `s` and `i` because this means that `f` can take a string or an int, the compiler will not allow it.

And lastly, if `args` is empty, you return `f` so the return type of `f` is the type of `f` itself, another buggy part of this code.

---

Looking at your examples, a simple solution would be:

```
type t = Str of string | Int of int

let rec apply f acc args =
  match args with x :: xs -> apply f (f acc x) xs | [] -> acc

(* Example 1 *)
let total =
  apply
    (fun acc x ->
      match x with Int d -> d + acc | Str _ -> failwith "Type error")
    0 [ Int 1; Int 2; Int 3 ]

(* Example 2 *)
let () =
  apply
    (fun () -> function
      | Str name -> Printf.printf "Name: %s\n" name
      | Int age -> Printf.printf "Age: %i\n" age)
    () [ Str "Bob"; Int 99 ]
```

Since you know the type you want to work on, you don't need GADT shenanigans, just let `f` handle the pattern matching and work with an accumulator

Comment: How do I fix my implementation of `apply`? Is it possible in OCaml?